# Problematic Skype installation

Tags: software-installation

I am completely new to Ubuntu OS and I am just getting familiar with the process of installing new apps.

I have recently installed Skype through Ubuntu Software center but I cannot run it. The Skype icon is visible in Unity yet, when I click on it, the icon bleeps for a few seconds, then nothing happens. I then tried running Skype directly from Terminal, getting the following error:

```
cannot locate the base snap: ubuntu-core: No such file or directory
```

In the software center it still states that Skype is not installed, however when I try to install it again, I obtain the following error:

```
Installation of Skype failed.
  Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
  snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request
```

I have performed the following set of commands in hope of clearing any possible remaining set of corrupted files:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I also need to point out, that right upon starting my new Ubuntu OS I tried to install Bitdefender for Ubuntu (from the official site), yet some errors occured and installation failed. I suspect some corrupt files may have remained, but I do not have error messages anymore. Additionally I have also looked through other similar threads regarding Skype problems on Ubuntu and found no apparent fixes.

Is there a way to completely clean your OS of any corrupt or damaged files, that might be causing this problem (apart from outright reinstalling Ubuntu)?

All the help is much appreciated!

Nejc

Comment: Hi Nejc and welcome to askUbuntu!  Skype is installed via a snap package. Therefore, please add the output of the following command to your post: `snap list `

Comment: Hi abu_bua! This is the output: `error: cannot list local snaps! cannot find publisher details: snap-declaration (QRDEfjn4WJYnm0FzDKwqqRZZI77awQEV; series:16) not found`

Comment: ok. try `sudo snap list` . If there is no snap or skype listed, install snap with `sudo install snap` and then install skype with `sudo snap install skype`

Comment: run- sudo apt purge snapd && sudo apt install snapd. Reboot the system, then run sudo snap install core ubuntu-core. Then try to install Skype- sudo snap install skype --classic. See if it works..

Comment: Thanks to you both, but @HattinGokbori87 your answer solved the issue. May I ask, what the core command in the middle was all about (I would like to get to know linux properly)?

Comment: I too am new to Ubuntu but I'll try to explain. **core** is the name of a Snap package. It is a dependency of Snapd (the main service which installs, runs Snaps). The Snap package **core** contains the low level dependencies (when you install an app, dependencies are the packages that aren’t part that app but are needed for the app to run properly) needed by all Snap apps. "ubuntu-core" is the name of a small operating system for IoT devices. You probably don't need it but I suggested it anyway as your error message mentions it.